# Hyperledger Fabric orderer container and client REST/Postman oversized record error

Tags: rest, docker-compose, postman, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

can't communicate with my Hyperledger Fabric's First-Network...

I can query and invoke from inside CLI docker container. Works fine!

But if i want to use Postman and Json to invoke or query from a client PC, than i get an error message in the orderer log:

`[grpc] Printf -> DEBU fc9 grpc: Server.Serve failed to complete security handshake from "10.xx.xx.xxx:56694": tls: oversized record received with length 21536`

The docker containers are on Suse Linux Server and not on locally VM.

I can ping my server and the Orderer-Container Port is mapped as default config(7050:7050)

I don't really know where to find the right cert.pem and key.pem files on the linux server filesystem. Tried different one in Postman = Option client certificates.

Also tried to search a solution but can't find a working one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hyperledger Fabric Peer and Orderer nodes only support direct communication using gRPC (which is protocol buffers over HTTP/2) APIs.  They do not offer an HTTP/REST interface.  Postman only supports HTTP endpoints so it will not work with peer or orderer nodes.  (the error you see if also likely due to the fact that postman was not using HTTPS).

If you want to attempt to use REST with the peer and orderer nodes, you might want to check out https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-rest which aims to provide a REST server in front of Hyperledger Fabric nodes.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Is your linked project Linux only? Because i need a windows solution for testing. Getting errors while execute npm link. Installed node 6.9.5 & npm & gyp